# Mule ESB 3 not getting port value from property file

Tags: properties, mule, esb

In my configuration file, I have this...

```
<spring:beans>
  <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:sbg-esb.properties" />
</spring:beans>
```

My properties file looks like this...

```
# Primary endpoint
esb.endpoint=localhost
esb.port=8081
```

The endpoint in the config file looks like this...

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${esb.endpoint}" port="${esb.port}" doc:name="Incoming localhost"/>
```

When starting the Mule Server I get the following error...

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'sbg-mobile-direction-flow' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'esb.port' in string value "${esb.port}
```

I don't get any error if all I do is use the esb.endpoint value in the properties file.  Once I put in the esb.port value the server breaks as described.  Is there a problem with integer values?  Am I screwing up the properties file somehow?  I thought perhaps using "port" was messing it up but I changed the name to esb.esb.port-like-thing and that got the same error.  Any help would be appreciated.

MORE INFO

I took the port out of the properties file.  I added the following.

```
esb.wsdlLocation=http\://dev.example.com/services/Mobile/LinkDevice/soap_server.php?wsdl
```

The Server breaks with the same error.  That would seem to mean that whatever is wrong doesn't have anything to do with port value itself.  No properties after the first one are being read correctly.

Comment: try after entering new line after `esb.port` value in properties file.

Comment: This is going to sound completely stupid.  I failed to mention I was using Anypoint Studio.  Apparently after changing the properties file you must refresh it in the Studio or it doesn't read the latest version.  I apologize for bother people with something that dumb.  Great googly-moogly.